# Rótulo para gráfico de barras - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, ciência-de-dados

Olá, tenho esse dataframe:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou gerando um gráfico de barras de mortes por dia, gostaria de colocar rótulos nas barras para mostrar número para cada dia.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.bar(df2['Data'], df2['dif_mortes'],  color='royalblue', width=0.8)
plt.xticks(df2['Data'], rotation=60, fontsize=14)
plt.yticks(fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode me ajudar nessa?

Answer (score -1):

Dê uma olhada neste [exemplo](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html) na documentação oficial do Matplotlib. É só seguir a mesma lógica.

Answer (score -1):

Veja se é possivel resolver da seguinte forma.

```
for i, v in enumerate(df['dif_mortes'].values()):
plt.text(x=i , y = 700 , s=f"{v}", 
         horizontalalignment='center', 
         verticalalignment='center', 
         fontdict=dict(fontsize=12) #mudar a fonte pro seu caso!
        )
```